# Overflow when using SpheroidalS2

Tags: special-functions, backslide

I want to compute the value of the radial oblate spheroidal wave function of the second kind. **However, I found the value at small arguments (for example $0.5I$ in the following code)  cannot be computed and it shows Overflow.**

But I can definitely look up the table 15.19 in Zhang's text book [1] that the following result should be $-0.6809057$. Does anyone know why Mathematica can not correctly compute it? Thank you.

Example 1 (failed): Run

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I , 0.5I]]
```

or

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I , 0.5I],10]
```

The return is

```
Overflow[]
```

Example 2 (success): Run

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I , 5I]]
```

The return is

```
-0.06805967763768572
```

**Update**

According to @MassDefect's suggestion, I tried the following code

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I,  I/2], 10]
```

It works and the result is

```
-0.6890905746 + 0.*10^-11 I
```

But if I type

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I,  I/10], 10]
```

It still shows

```
Overflow[]
```

**Updata #2**

According to @Bill Watts's answer, one can try different precision and maybe there is no Overflow. For example, if one run

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, I/10], 50]
```

The result will be

```
-1.13893813158018132761330789352859720024513682988326 + 0.*10^-51 I
```

This is a good trick. However, it can not solve my problem in two aspects.

Firstly, I tried many precision scheme but it always return Overflow:

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, 0], 200]
```

Secondly, I want a big numerical table for further computations. For example, the argument may begin with $0$ and end with $10 I$ with the step of $0.001I$. The Bill Watts's answer can not be applied because the requirement of the precision is different for different arguments.

[1] Zhang, S., & Jin, J. (1996). Computation of Special Functions. New York: John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: `i` should be `I`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo @xzczd  . Because I use [Esc] ii [Esc] in Mathematica which looks like "i", so I typed "i" in the original post. Now I changed it into "I" according to your suggestion. Please note it is not a simple mistake and this thread should not be closed. I added a successful example where the argument "0.5" is changed into "5".

Comment: @xzczd Does it mean the question will not be seen by others if it is closed?

Comment: When questions are closed they are only viewable by the author and people with at least 3000 reputation. I feel that this question may have been closed prematurely as "i" to "I" didn't fix the issue you were experiencing. However, I think if you provide an explicit number of decimals to `N`, it avoids machine precision computation and provides a result. `N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, I/2], 10]` seems to work for me. Notice that I have to keep the value inside `Spheroidal` as an exact value to avoid the overflow.

Comment: Click on the `...` button and select "Show Stack Trace."  Click on the `...1...` to see the full expression of a `LinearSolve` problem that leads to `Overflow[]`.

Comment: @MassDefect  Hi, thank you so much for answering me in details. I tried N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, I/2], 10] which works on my computer. although some warnings are shown. I tried N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, 0.5 I], 10] again but it still shows Overflow[]. By the way, I also tired N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I,  I/10], 10] and it also shows Overflow[].

Comment: @MichaelE2  Hi, thank you. There are many numbers there, but I don't understand the meaning of them. You may try `N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, I/10], 10]` if you have Mathematica in hand.

Comment: Try `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500}, N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, I/10], 10]]`. (You can set `$MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity`, if you want. The bound is there to prevent computations from using too much time and memory, though.)

Comment: `N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, 0.5 I], 10]` does not work because 0.5 is a machine precision number. It looks like during the evaluation, you generate a number larger than `$MachineMaxNumber`. To avoid this, you can use arbitrary precision or infinite precision (like my example), and only call `N` on arbitrary/infinite precision numbers.

Comment: In version 10.1 under Windows 7 x64 `N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, 0.5 I], 10]` returns `-0.689091 + 0. I` and `N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, I/10], 10]` returns `-1.1389381316 + 0.*10^-11 I`.  I am tagging this as a regression; please correct me if it is not.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for the comment. However, I found it still returns Overflow for the argument $0$, i.e.: `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500}, N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, 0], 10]]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What does 'regression' mean in this case?

Comment: I meant that the function or performance of *Mathematica* declined compared to an older version.  *Retrogression* would have been a better choice of word.

Comment: I tested the code in _v9.0.1_ and it gives the correct result after correcting the typo, so I thought your `i` is polluted. Happy to see the correct answer is found by other guys.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you have to fool around with the precision on a case by case basis.

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, I/2]]
(*-0.6890905745631529 + 0.*I*)
```

works, but

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, I/10]]
```

gets an overflow.  However,

```
N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, I/10], 50]
-1.13893813158018132761330789352859720024513682988326 + 0.*10^-51 I
```

works.

In any case, I would always use exact numbers with this function.

Comment: Good tricks. However, I tried many precisions like 50, 100, 200 and it is still Overflow if the input is `N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, 0], 50]`. I want to generate a big numerical table for further computations so I expect a better solution

Comment: For that one you get pretty close with `N[SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, 10^-50], 50]`, but maybe someone else can come up with a solution that covers all inputs.

Answer (score 7):

Please report this issue to Wolfram support. It seems that [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve) has a bug related to the new in M12 handling of machine number underflow. As an example, the following extracts the [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve) call that doesn't work in M12, but does in M11.1:

```
ls = Reap[
    TracePrint[
        SpheroidalS2Prime[0, 0, -I, 0.],
        _LinearSolve,
        TraceInternal->True,
        TraceAction->Sow
    ]
][[2,1,6]]
```

> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
>
> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
>
> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
>
> General::stop: Further output of General::ovfl will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> [image]

In M11.1 the above evaluates without error:

[image]

> {-2.0000000000000000000000000, 2.6666666666666666666666667, \
>   -3.200000000000000000000000, 3.657142857142857142857143, \
>   -4.063492063492063492063492, 4.432900432900432900432900, \
>   -4.773892773892773892773893, 5.092152292152292152292152, \
>   -5.391690662278897573015220, 5.675463855030418497910758, \
>   -5.945724038603295569239842, 6.204233779412134507032878, \
>   -6.452403130588619887314193, 6.691381024314124327585089, \
>   -6.922118301014611373363886, 7.145412439757018191859495, \
>   -7.361940089446624803734025, 7.572281234859385512412140, \
>   -7.776937484450179715450306, 7.976346137897620220974673, \
>   -8.170891165651220714169177, 8.360911890433807242405669, \
>   -8.546709932443447403348018, 8.728554824623095220440529, \
>   -8.906688596554178796367886, 9.081329549427790145316276, \
>   -9.252675389983031468812810, 9.420905851619086586427588, \
>   -9.586184901647491614259651, 9.748662611844906726365747, \
>   -9.908476753022692082535677, 10.065754161800830052099736, \
>   -10.220611918136227437516655, 10.373158364675574115688545, \
>   -10.523493993149133160843451, 10.671712218404754754658148, \
>   -10.817900057013039066365794, 10.962138724439879587250671, \
>   -11.104504162419618283188991}

In M12 we get overflow errors:

[image]

> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
>
> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
>
> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
>
> General::stop: Further output of General::ovfl will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> {Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
>    Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
>    Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
>    Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
>    Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
>    Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[], 
>    Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[]}

As a workaround, you can override the evaluation of [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve) so that it defaults to the slower and less robust method using [`Inverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inverse):

```
Unprotect[LinearSolve];
LinearSolve[s1_SparseArray,s2_SparseArray] /; !TrueQ@$LSFlag := Block[{$LSFlag=True},
    Quiet[
        Check[
            LinearSolve[s1,s2],
            Inverse[s1].s2, 
            General::ovfl
        ],
        General::ovfl
    ]
]
Protect[LinearSolve];
```

Then:

```
SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, .1 I]
SpheroidalS2[0, 0, -I, 0.]
```

> -1.13894 + 0. I
>
> -1.25234 + 0. I